# Lag Function usage in python to shift the data and create new variables

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, lag

I have a dataset as below:

The '**FIRST**' and '**SECOND**' variable has eight combination each(which can change) an the '**SCORE**' has a value for each combination

```
     FIRST  SECOND  SCORE
0       1       1  38147
1       2       1    567
2       3       1      0
3       4       1      0
4       5       1      0
5       6       1      0
6       7       1      0
7       8       1      0
8       1       2   3099
9       2       2  30460
10      3       2   2372
11      4       2      0
12      5       2      0
13      6       2      0
14      7       2      0
15      8       2    267
```

I wanted to create 8 new variables with suffix as 'S' (the number of new variables is same as number of unique values in 'FIRST' or 'SECOND' and the **shift the value of 'SCORE' with one lag in each new variables.**

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
      FIRST  SECOND  SCORE     S1       S2       S3       S4       S5      S6      S7   S8
0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
1       2       1    567  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN NaN
6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN NaN
7       8       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0 NaN
8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
9       2       2  30460   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
10      3       2   2372  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
11      4       2      0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN NaN
14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN NaN
15      8       2    267      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0 NaN
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in python?

Below is equivalent code in R language which accomplishes this using data.table package

**R code**

number_of_bids  <- 8

```
test[, paste0('S',seq(1:number_of_bids)):= shift(SCORE,1:number_of_bids, NA_real_,"lag"), by = SECOND]
```

Below is the **input python data** for reference:

```
#Ceate dataframe
data = [
    [1,1,38147],
    [2,1,567],
    [3,1,0],
    [4,1,0],
    [5,1,0],
    [6,1,0],
    [7,1,0],
    [8,1,0],
    [1,2,3099],
    [2,2,30460],
    [3,2,2372],
    [4,2,0],
    [5,2,0],
    [6,2,0],
    [7,2,0],
    [8,2,267],
       
]

#dataframe
test1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'SCORE'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods:

1. `.shift` and `pd.concat`:

   ```py
   In [324]: pd.concat([dat,dat.groupby(['SECOND'])['SCORE'].shift(), dat.groupby(['SECOND'])['SCORE'].shift(2)], axis=1)
   Out[324]: 
       FIRST  SECOND  SCORE    SCORE    SCORE
   0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN
   1       2       1    567  38147.0      NaN
   2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0
   3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0
   4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0
   5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0
   6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0
   7       8       1      0      0.0      0.0
   8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN
   9       2       2  30460   3099.0      NaN
   10      3       2   2372  30460.0   3099.0
   11      4       2      0   2372.0  30460.0
   12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0
   13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0
   14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0
   15      8       2    267      0.0      0.0
   ```

   (and rename the subsequent columns).
2. `for` loop and `.shift`:

   ```py
   In [337]: for lag in range(1, 5):
        ...:   dat['S' + str(lag)] = dat.groupby(['SECOND'])['SCORE'].shift(lag)
        ...: 

   In [338]: dat
   Out[338]: 
       FIRST  SECOND  SCORE       S1       S2       S3       S4
   0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
   1       2       1    567  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
   2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN
   3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN
   4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0
   5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0
   6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
   7       8       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
   8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
   9       2       2  30460   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
   10      3       2   2372  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN
   11      4       2      0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN
   12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0
   13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0
   14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0
   15      8       2    267      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
   ```

---

Data

```py
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({
  'FIRST': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],dtype='int64',index=pd.Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='int64')),
  'SECOND': pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],dtype='int64',index=pd.Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='int64')), 
  'SCORE': pd.Series([38147, 567, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3099, 30460, 2372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 267],dtype='int64',index=pd.Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='int64'))
}, index=pd.Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype='int64'))
```